My render is black
I just started using blender and I'm using the mesh Suzanne monkey as a practice tool and whenever I go into the render viewport. it always appear black. ive watched YouTube videos and all but nothing is working....im using Blender 4.3. I have tried changing the scene world the lights and everything

Please at least include a screenshot of your Blender screen which you can create from Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu. Then follow How to upload an image to a post. It would also help to share your Blend file here.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
